# Resharper Create Property for multiple properties

Tags: properties, resharper, auto-generate, generate

Resharper Code Generation offers to write property names which at-the-time-of-writing do not exist in the respective class. If I select the context action menu "Create property..." I can easily generate the code for it.

**Question:** How can I generate code for multiple properties and/or methods? Is there a 'bulk create properties' method somewhere?

[image: Resharper -> Create Property]